# SQL CLR # Publishing Issue MSSQL 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating C# stored procedure in a way as described here:

[SQL CRL Setup](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/g_arora/step-by-step-create-clr-store-procedure/)

But when installing SQL CLR C# stored procedure into SQL 2008 and it not showing in assembly list after publish. The generated script is as follows:

```
 /*
    Deployment script for Attend

    This code was generated by a tool.
    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    the code is regenerated.
    */

    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


    GO
    :setvar DatabaseName "Attend"
    :setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Attend"
    :setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
    :setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"

    GO
    :on error exit
    GO
    /*
    Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
    To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
    SET NOEXEC OFF; 
    */
    :setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
    GO
    IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
        BEGIN
            PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
            SET NOEXEC ON;
        END


    GO
    USE [$(DatabaseName)];


    GO
    PRINT N'Update complete.';


    GO
```

> > Also enabled SQLCMD in options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the referred CLR article. Though it is fine in general, there is no need to create a CLR object which executes simple SELECT statements.

I created a [SQL CLR split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/split-2d-array-with-sql-clr-function.aspx) when **string_split** was not introduced and a CLR function to [read file properties](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/clr-stored-procedure-to-read-file-property-in-sqlserver.aspx)

The above code does nothing. Just prints some messages, that is all

To add the new assembly file (dll) for the CLR object to the SQL Server, you need CREATE ASSEMBLY command.
After you successfully execute Create Assembly command, the dll will be listed in **sys.assemblies**

Also you need to configure maybe trustworthy property, etc.
Please check the above referenced two articles on CLR procedures.
I hope it helps.

Comment: I have published it via visual studio, so should I need to modify generated script and run it again. Result shows **Update Completed**

Comment: I actually did not publish using VS. But if you can just take the DLL and put it on a place where SQL user has access like a local folder on SQL Server instance. Then you can execute the CREATE ASSEMBLY script on the target database that you want to have your CLR functions